# Apply SortBy and then ordering elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the list:

```
a = {{1.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 4.0}, {4.0, 1.5}, {1.2, 4.0}, {2., 
   8.}, {9.0, 9.0}};
```

When I apply `SortBy[a,Last]` I get the following:

```
{{4., 1.5}, {1., 3.}, {4., 3.}, {1., 4.}, {1.2, 4.}, {2., 8.}, {9., 
  9.}}
```

My question: For those with similar Last part, How can I order them from Largest to smallest, so the final output would look like:

```
{{4., 1.5}, {4., 3.}, {1., 3.}, {1.2, 4.}, {1., 4.}, {2., 8.}, {9., 
  9.}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SortBy[a, {Last, Minus@*First}]
```

> {{4., 1.5}, {4., 3.}, {1., 3.}, {1.2, 4.}, {1., 4.}, {2., 8.}, {9., 9.}}

Comment: Many thanks Carl. A great helper here.